# Difficulty with Recursive Macro

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to remove code duplication in this Rust code using a macro:

```
enum AnyError { Error(Error), ParseIntError(ParseIntError), }
impl From<Error> for AnyError {
    fn from(err: Error) -> AnyError { AnyError::Error(err) }
}
impl From<ParseIntError> for AnyError {
    fn from(err: ParseIntError) -> AnyError { AnyError::ParseIntError(err) }
}
```

This is the macro code I'm trying to get working, which I believe should generate the above:

```
enum AnyError {
    Error(Error),
    ParseIntError(ParseIntError),
}

macro_rules! any_error {
    ($n: ident) => ();
    ($n: ident, $x:ident, $($y:ident),*) => {
        impl From<$x> for $n {
            fn from(err: $x) -> $n {
                $n::$x(err)
            }
        }
        any_error!($n, $($y),*);
    };
}

any_error!(AnyError, Error, ParseIntError);
```

This is the error I'm getting from the compiler:

```
error: unexpected end of macro invocation
  --> src/main.rs:17:28
   |
9  | macro_rules! any_error {
   | ---------------------- when calling this macro
...
17 |         any_error!($n, $($y),*);
   |                            ^ missing tokens in macro arguments
```

I've tried a bunch of different variants of this.  If I remove the recursive call to `any_error!` then it successfully generates one of the `From` impls, so that part seems fine.  Does anyone know what's wrong, or what the compiler error actually means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your macro handles *zero* variants, and *two or more* variants, but fails when there is *exactly one*:

```rust
any_error!(AnyError, Error);  // None of the cases handle this!
```

A possible fix is to move the `,` into the `$y` matcher, so that in the *exactly one* case, the macro doesn't expect a trailing comma:

```rust
macro_rules! any_error {
    ($n: ident) => ();
    ($n: ident, $x:ident $(, $y:ident)*) => {
        impl From<$x> for $n {
            fn from(err: $x) -> $n {
                $n::$x(err)
            }
        }
        any_error!($n $(, $y)*);
    };
}
```

Alternatively, you can put the `impl` inside the `$()*` block and skip the recursion altogether:

```rust
macro_rules! any_error {
    ($n: ident) => ();
    ($n: ident, $($x:ident),*) => {
        $(
            impl From<$x> for $n {
                fn from(err: $x) -> $n {
                    $n::$x(err)
                }
            }
        )*
    };
}
```